# Raspberry pi 3B+ Slow download, fast upload on LAN

Tags: raspbian

Hello I have connected my pi 3B+ to Google Wifi (1000M boardband)  with LAN cable, with speedtest-cli I've got the following result:

Download: 4.35 MBit/s
Upload: 95.66 Mbit/s

---

My PC with Gigabit Ethernet can archive >800MBit/s for both download and upload speed. Also it's a fresh install of Raspbian for the pi. Any idea on whats going on? Thanks!

Comment: Pi3B+ isn’t 1GB - it’s limited by usb 2.0 speed, Doesn't explain the download speed though. https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/getting-gigabit-networking

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable flow control on your router.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=215785#p1327157

Comment: That thread suggests flow control should be turned on !

Answer (score 0):

Previously I was connecting the Pi to a Google Wifi Mesh node, i just tried to connect the Pi directly to the main node and now I get 200Mbit/s for both download and upload. Seems this issue is not related to Pi.

Thank you guys!